# Regex Replace A Word In Parentheses INCLUDING The Parentheses

Tags: yahoo-pipes

in Yahoo Pipes I'm struggling to find a way of removing the brackets around a word, as well as the word itself. How do I replace "(Active)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\(Active\)
```

Escape the `(` and `)` characters.